# hyperledger fabric invoke.js "Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am able to invoke my chaincode from docker cli successfully (fabric-shim).
i ran enrollAdmin.js and registerUser.js sucessfully,
but when i try to run invoke.js or query.js, i get `Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]`.

Comment: Have you created your channel and joined your peer into your network?

Comment: @Dylan, yes i am successfully invoke chain code function from docker cli.

Comment: @Dylan, peer channel list  ,
2018-09-23 05:03:20.325 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Channels peers has joined: 
mychannel

Comment: I am using basic_network to install my chaincode

Comment: Could you provided more information about peer's log, invoke.js, and query.js?

Comment: @Dylan here is docker logs     
WARN 044 channel [mychannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com"

Comment: @Dylan, i am using https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/fabcar/invoke.js, by changing chaincodeId, fcn and args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are limited information shows above, the peer log give the essential hint about the problem:

```
WARN 044 channel [mychannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com"
```

Here is the suggestions that may help your to solve this problem:

1. Change your peer's logging level to `DEBUG` on docker-compose file, you will be more easily to find the solution followed by the debug information.
2. Make sure your CA container is running and its logs not throws out error, like some certifications verify error, which commonly causes by wrong configuration.
3. Now that the logs shows up some information about x509 ECDSA, which related to the signature and and the peers endorsement keycert. Also, this keycerts may storage on `/tmp/hfc-key-store` or any other place that you defined on you code. Try to clean up this temporary file and restart network again.
4. Noticed that your are using the fabric-sample repo, I think this problem may not caused by some code issues since you just modified a few parameters. So I recommend you to follow [this tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/write_first_app.html#) to get the right step.

Comment: i had issue in hfc-key-store as you said in suggestion 3.  
credentials were getting saved in current directory -> hfc-key-store where i was running enrollAdmin.js. Network was referring to ~/.hfc-key-store folder, But for some reason credentials were not created in ~/.hfc-key-store. So i copied credentials from current directory to ~/.hfc-key-store. Now inoke works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue.

I found out then channel name in network config and the channel I created was different. So I changed the channel name in the network config and it got fixed.