# hyperledger fabric: unable to invoke chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created the channels, joined peers into the channels updated anchor peers, and instantiated the chaincode in command lines. Then I would like to invoke the chaincode through frontend and rest api that I have created, following the balance transfer example. However, it shows this error when I invoked:

```
[2019-04-19T14:38:05.942] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - invoke chaincode proposal: Error : Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [sntschannel] creator org [BankMSP]
[2019-04-19T14:38:05.942] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - invoke chaincode proposal: Error : Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [sntschannel] creator org [BankMSP]
[2019-04-19T14:38:05.943] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Failed to invoke chaincode. cause:invoke chaincode proposal: Error : Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [sntschannel] creator org [BankMSP]
```

and in the peer's log, it said

```
2019-04-19 06:30:28.563 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 15d channel [sntschannel]: creator certificate is not valid: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer or an orderer identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs: [[0xc003b4b770 0xc003b4b7a0 0xc003b4b7d0]], MSP: [BankMSP]
2019-04-19 06:30:28.563 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 15e unary call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-04-19T06:30:28.56Z", "grpc.service": "protos.Endorser", "grpc.method": "ProcessProposal", "grpc.peer_address": "xxx.xx.x.x:xxxxx", "error": "access denied: channel [sntschannel] creator org [BankMSP]", "grpc.code": "Unknown", "grpc.call_duration": "3.653274ms"}
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Change your peer's logging level to `DEBUG` on docker-compose file,it would be easier to isolate the problem and find the solution followed by the debug information. Check out this answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52464492/6138595

Comment: looks like peer belongs to BankMSP and that org doesn't belong to the channel. Maybe try the same code from cli and if it fails then recreate the channel(ensure you've included the org and its msp in the channel)

Comment: Thanks for your helps! But finally I found out the problem. When I was following others' tutorial to use fabric CA, I have set multiple roles to that user which is not allowed according to the error message.